# From DWG to shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dwg

I can't export a project (road) from AutoCAD Map3D to shapefile (QGIS). I tried also with Leica Infinity, but the only data I have exported are my benchmarks, but not the polylines of the road. I tried many times changing the Coordinates System but still nothing to do.

Comment: MAPEXPORT in AutoCAD will export to shapefile > https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2021/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-55FE7920-51ED-42AB-B52C-0AC25C198E46-htm.html

Answer (score 1):

You can export it as dxf and import it in QGIS. Please make sure there are no blocks or XREFs in the dxf. Also in the import screen you need to select the different geometry types(points, linestring, polygon)  you want to import.